# Two paper appear to imply collapse via coloring $P_5$-free graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory, graph-colouring, graph-classes

Found this from graphclasses.org.

Two papers give conflicting results for coloring [$P_5$-free](http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_396.html)
graphs  which appear to imply $P=NP$.

From [Polynomial-time algorithm for vertex k-colorability of P_5-free graphs](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/1959697_Polynomial-time_algorithm_for_vertex_k-colorability_of_P_5-free_graphs)

> Abstract. We give the first polynomial-time algorithm for coloring vertices of P5 -free graphs with k colors. This settles an open problem and generalizes several previously known results.

From [Some new hereditary classes where graph coloring remains NP-hard, p 5](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X05001019)

> ... Coloring is NP-hard in $2K_2$-free ... and $\{C_5,P_5\} \cup \ldots$-free

$2K_2-free \subset P_5-free$ and the other class contains $P_5$.

According to graphclasses, another reason for hardness is
clique cover on the complement (another paper), click +Details
for references.

Question:

> What is wrong with this seeming contradiction?

Comment: The first paper shows that there exists a function $f$ such that it can be decided if a $P_5$-free graph can be $k$-colored in time $O(n^{f(k)})$. This means that for each fixed $k$, the problem can be solved in polynomial time in $n$. This is an interesting result since the trivial algorithm would use $O(k^n)$ time. However, the result does not give a polynomial time algorithm for CHROMATIC NUMBER of $P_5$-free graphs, since $\sum_{k=1..n} n^{f(k)}$ is not polynomial in $n$. That CHROMATIC NUMBER is NP-hard for $P_5$-free graphs is even mentioned in (the conference version of) the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of those papers is about k-colorability and the other of

those papers does not specify a constant number of colors.

(For a similar example, consider k-variable-SAT versus SAT.)

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand. The second paper defines on p.1 "MCP: Find in G = (V , E) a minimum number k of stable sets S1 , . . . , Sk , which cover
V (i.e. S1 ∪ · · · ∪ Sk = V ). This minimum number is the chromatic number chi(G) of G.. The quoted result hardness of MCP. In the first paper $k$ is given, so binary search will find minimum $k$. What is wrong with this? According to graphclasses $k$-colorability is NP-hard.

Comment: "In the first paper $k$" determines _which_ of [3-coloring,4-coloring,5-coloring,6-coloring,7-coloring,...] is the current problem. $\;$

Comment: Yes, but this is enough. We know $k  \le n$. Try $k=2,3,4,...n$ and stop if you find coloring. Each call is polynomial in $n$ and there are at most $n$ calls, which is polynomial in $n$.

Comment: Each call being polynomial in $n$ is not enough for their sum to be polynomial in $n$. $\:$ (Consider (n^2)+(n^3)+(n^4)+...+(n^(n-1)).) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Why n^(n-1)? This worse than exponential in $n$. Each call is $O(n^d)$ for some $d$, so the total is $\sum_{k=2}^n O(n^d)$.

Comment: n^(n-1) is a simple example of what you could get for $\: k = n\hspace{-0.04 in}-\hspace{-0.05 in}1 \;$. $\;\;\;$ If you could show that each "call is $O(n^d)$" with neither d nor the big-O constants depending on k, then you'd (presumably) have P=NP. $\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: I don't see exact running time in the paper, but I wouldn't call n^(n-1) polynomial in n, since it is worse that exponential for all n large enough.

Comment: They wouldn't either. $\:$ However, they _would_ call n^k polynomial in n. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: If $d$ depends on $k$, for infinitely many $(k,n)$ they will have running time worse than exponential, so I wouldn't call this polynomial. If the implied constant is bounded by fixed degree polynomial in $k$ and $d$ is constant this is polynomial for me. Isn't this close to calling SAT solver of $n$ variables and $m$ clauses with running time $n^{f(m)}$ polynomial?

Comment: No, but it's close to calling that "polynomial for $m$-clause-SAT". $\;$

Comment: Never mind. The first paper definitely contradicts complexity of $k$-colorability with graphclasses:  http://graphclasses.org/classes/gc_396.html

Comment: How does that link support your comment? $\;$

Comment: Max clique is Np-complete. But 2-clique is polynomial time solvable (in $n^2$ time). And we can do 3-clique in $n^3$ time. In fact, for ever fixed k we can solve k-clique in $n^k$ time. But this still doesnt imply P=NP

Comment: You appear right. Just learned that their algorithm is exponential in k. Thank you.